# Specfic Email Address Validation using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a registration form where email address is needed.
I need to allow the email addresses that belongs only to domain("NAME"@Mobily.com.sa) this is for employees that working for "MOBILY"
Also we need to disallow the emails that is ( "NAME".c@mobily.com.sa ) where those emails that ends up with (.c) belongs to the contractors  working for "Mobily".

The Idea is to allow the employees and disallow the contractors from registration.

Please Advise the proper REGEX to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to prevent **.c** from occurring right before the **@**.

```
/[\w\.\+-]+?(?!\.c).{2}@mobily\.com\.sa/g
```

See the regex in action here:
https://regex101.com/r/i0Rg34/2

Comment: Many Many Thanks Boss :) very simple and working like a magic for me :)

Comment: Sure thing man :).. If this answer has worked for you. please be sure to choose this as the winning answer and upvote. Thanks

Comment: @Jordan you should add make sure your expression matches the whole input, otherwise this e-mail could be used too: my.name@mobility.com.sa.someOtherTLD. Also the Domain is not case-insentive

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var regEx = /^(\w+)@(mobily\.com\.sa)$/i;
```

In case you want to support name as "abc.def", do

```
var regEx = /^(\w+\.?\w+)@(mobily\.com\.sa)$/i;
```

Examples:

```
regEx.test("ab212121c@mobily.com.sa")  //true
regEx2.test("ab212121.c@mobily.com.sa") //false
```

Comment: matches mails from different domains like mobily-com.sa. The . in the domain should be escaped. Won't work if Name contains separator for first and last name

Comment: Thanks radicarl. Changed it.
About separator, for that OP should provide list of all special characters he wants to support. Currently I have provided support for "."

Answer (score 1):

The following regex can have a everything as name except names ending with .c

```regex
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?!\.c).{2}@mobily\.com\.sa$/i
```

See here
https://regex101.com/r/6vgQbj/2

Answer (score -1):

please use this:

[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@mobily.com.sa

Comment: matches mails with xxxx.c@mobily.com.sa or xxx@mobily-com.sa

Comment: The pattern should always end at "mobily.com.sa". In your case, there can be any character after "mobily.com.sa" and it will still return true.